# Yii URL Rules Rewrite

Tags: url, yii

I have the folowing `URL` rule in `main.php` under `urlManager`, `rules`:

`the-urly-bird` => `blog/content/index`,

This page (http://www.accesstheflock.io/the-urly-bird) has 10 pages of content. I would like each page to have it's own `URL` like: http://www.accesstheflock.io/the-urly-bird/page/2.

The path for each page is: `?r=blog/content/index&Content_page=2`

Please provide `URL` rules for `main.php` to make this work. This is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Add this in your controller 
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Blog',array(
   'pagination'=>array(
    'pageVar'=>'page'
   )
  ));

Comment: Thanks. I tried this. As you can see on [link](http://www.accesstheflock.io/the-urly-bird) it didn't work. The **urlManager** rules overwrite it. On the localhost it worked as showing the page variable in the URL, however. Thank you. It would be good to have rules in the urlManager please.

Comment: I was able to write working URL rules and add a jQuery on click event handler to redirect to the right url for the pagination.  'the-urly-bird/page/<page:\d+>'=>'blog/content/index',
    'the-urly-bird' => 'blog/content/index', $('li.page a').on('click', function() {
    //Redirects
      window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
      return false;
  });

Answer (score 0):

I was able to write working URL rules and add a jQuery on click event handler to redirect to the right url for the pagination.

main.php

```
'the-urly-bird/page/<page:\d+>'=>'blog/content/index', 
'the-urly-bird' => 'blog/content/index',
```

view

```
$('li.page a').on('click', function() { //Redirects 
  window.location.href = $(this).attr('href'); 
  return false; 
}); –
```